# Where to find Bot builder SDK V3 Visual Studio.net template for C#

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Where can I find the link to the **C# project template for V3 Bot framework SDK**?
Was this project template deprecated by Microsoft after the release of V4 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, they are focusing on the v4 framework and have moved their efforts there.
The only place I was able to find the template was in [this github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/tree/master/CSharp/Generator)

Comment: In addition, the templates were provided throught this link `http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate` which is no longer pointing to v3 but v4 template now